# Google App script - Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

On `OnOpen()` function I run a custom function that checks whether the user token is valid or not but I get the following error from google.

```
Google Apps Script: Error: Error: Exception: You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permissions:
```

I've already checked online and the solution was to add the following in the `appscript.json`

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request
```

I've added that but still, I keep getting the same error from google.

This is how my `appscript.json` looks like

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

this is my `onOpen()` function

```
const onOpen = () => {
  const { token } = getPresetData();
  if (token) {
    const isTokenValid = validateUserToken();  // <---- this is where I make a request to my server 
    if(isTokenValid){
      console.log('token is valid');
      getMenu(true);
    }else{
      console.log('token is not valid');
      getMenu(false)
    }
  } else {
    console.log('token is undefined');
    getMenu(false);
  }
};
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Simple triggers (like onOpen) cannot access services that require authorization. Maybe rename your function and then set up an installable onopen trigger on that function and see if that helps?

Comment: I am planning to release the script as an add-on for my company so just wondering to ask will the custom trigger be available to all users?

Comment: I believe you should be able to let them create the trigger when the add-on is installed. If not, you can create a function (accessible in the add-on menu) that does exactly that.

Comment: The usual workflow would be to use the `onOpen` trigger to display a menu, and move the current code from `onOpen` to  a function triggered through this menu. See [Custom menus for editor add-ons](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/menus). Does this solve your issue?